# How to pluck the second value in a url after the first slash, in a string that could have many slashes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are countless regex questions out there, but I was unable to find one that fits my situation.

Suppose I have the following `pathname`:

```
/u/some_user/create/initial
```

How can I extract `'some_user'` from this string?

I got pretty close with this:

```js
const pathname = '/u/some_user/create/initial';

const result = pathname.match(/(\/u\/)(.{1,}\/)(.+)/);

console.log('result', result);
```

This *could* potentially work if the string was `'/u/some_user/create'` -- It would return `some_user/`, and I could filter out the slash at the end. But if the string has more slashes, as above, then this just returns `'some_user/create/'`.

How can I achieve plucking out just `'some_user'`?

Comment: Preferably regex.. but as a side note, how reliable is the URL API? First I'm hearing of it, honestly. What if the username value is 4 slashes down, will it pick it up?

Comment: Are you forced to use regex, or could you simply use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then access the second array element?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I prematurely suggested to use the URL API, but the issue lies within the pathname, so that one won’t help.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up temporarily using split earlier today, but I'm wondering what the regex would be for this case

Comment: The problem is that split just returns everything after `/u/`, including all subpaths after the username

Comment: By experience, any standardised API is more reliable than a self-made regex. They are tempting, but often based on a superficial knowledge of the standard. My favourite example are e-mail tests. (:

Comment: “The problem is that split just returns everything after /u/” Based on your question I cannot make out the problem there?

Comment: I'd support the idea of using the split, but if you really want a generalized regex that gets you the content between 2nd and 3rd slash, you can use `(\/[^\/]+\/)([^\/]+)(.*)`

Comment: Well if I do `'/u/some_user/create/initial'.split('/u/')`, this yields -> `['', 'some_user/create/initial']` -- I need just `'some_user'`

Comment: or if you need it to be found strictly after "\u\" and before the next slash, you can instead use `.*\/u\/([^\/]+).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
\/u\/([^/]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\/u\/` Match `/u/`
- `(` Capture *group 1*

  - `[^/]+` Match 1+ characters other than `/` using a negated character class.
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCCLKw/1).

```js
const regex = /\/u\/([^/]+)/;
[
  "/u/some_user/create/initial",
  "/u/some_user/create",
  "test/123/u/some_user/a/b/c"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
});
```

If you don't want to cross newlines, and there has to be a `/` after some_user:

```
\/u\/([^/\s]+)\/
```

See another [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2WXcj/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about legacy browser support, which includes Safari and any browser installed on Mac/iOS, then this would work:

```
/(?<=^\/u\/)[^\/]+/
```

```js
var regexp = /(?<=^\/u\/)[^\/]+/;

console.log( `/u/some_user/create/initial`.match( regexp ) );
console.log( `/u/`.match( regexp ) );
console.log( `/wrong/format/url`.match( regexp ) );
console.log( `/u/another_user/create/initial`.match( regexp ) );
```

https://regex101.com/r/NmtKxD/1

Answer (score 0):

Not withstanding the request for a regular expression, the specific problem is easily solved with either of two common string methods.

**string.split**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Returns an array of substrings demarked according to any character or characters provided as an argument. By splitting the string at each of the slashes, the required string is element[2] of the resulting array (since element [0] will be empty -being derived from 0 characters before the first "/").

viz:

```js
const url = "/u/some_user/create/initial";

requiredString = url.split("/")[2];

console.log(requiredString); // "some_user";
```

**string slice**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Where the position, either numerically or by reference to known bounding test, of the target substring is available, `string.slice` provides an easy method to extract the required substring.

In this example bounding text parts are used to extract the required field:

```js
const url = "/u/some_user/create/initial";

beforeText = "/u/";
afterText = "/create";

let requiredString = url.slice(url.indexOf(beforeText)+beforeText.length, url.indexOf(afterText));

console.log(requiredString); // "some-user"
```

Both of these methods are reliable core javascript, supported by all interpreters.